# How do I get a static variable to appear as a field in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift

I added a label to my storyboard and did a CTRL drag to my ViewController.swift file, set as an Outlet and gave it a name but it's not clear to me how to print a variable such as the following to my label.

```
var userName = "Ted"
```

In Swift playgrounds I can run the following and it prints the variable just fine but I can't make it do that in the label/IBOutlet once I compile the app.

```
var userName = "Ted"
print(userName)
```

Here's my ViewController so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var userName = "Ted"

    @IBOutlet var userNameLabel: UILabel? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(userName)
    }
}
```

I'm using Xcode 9.3.1 and Swift 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your label is an outlet and it is connected through your storyboard, change:

```
@IBOutlet var userNameLabel: UILabel? = nil
```

to:

```
@IBOutlet var userNameLabel: UILabel!
```

Then in `viewDidLoad`, instead of `print`, set the label's `text`:

```
userNameLabel.text = userName
```

Answer (score 0):

Every label have one property called **text** which is used to set/get value to/from label for example::

```
 lblObj.text = "text you want to display"
 print(lblObj.text) // output::  "text you want to display"
```

text property will only except **string** type, since your username is of type string you can assign it like below

```
userNameLabel.text = userName
```